# Lazy math program?

Tags: math-software

I'm writing a software that does simple mathematical calculations for lazy people.

I need ideas.
I already wrote some pieces of code that calculates 'Quadratic formula', but I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Stop coding and spread links to http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: And if you *really* want to do this, you might want to pick up a book or ten about symbolic computation. Every time I have to deal with a messy algebraic expression I am thankful that computer algebra systems exist.

Comment: You could better contribute to Maxima or Sage once you're good enough. Solving quadratic equations in software is very trivial. Try doing symboling integration.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://projecteuler.net/. It is not quite what you were asking for, but it contains many math problems that one must use programming to solve.

Comment: I've seen so many little apps that solve quadratics, and they're good programming exercises, but imho they shouldn't be released because they're just a lot of dressed up code for solving a trivial problem. If you want to do something more challenging and useful: 1) Try coding something that numerically solves a univariate polynomial of n'th order; 2) Extend that to solve multivariate polynomial systems of n'th order (numerically); 3) Learn the theory behind Groebner bases, and symbolically solve multivariate polynomial systems of n'th order.

Comment: @Gilead: Thank you :) Awesome name!

Comment: To the commenters: do click on the OP's page and check out his profile.  I agree completely with the content of the replies, but I think it's an investment in the future not to be too discouraging to young people.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Jonas T, I don't know why he didn't make his comment an answer.

Symbolic integration of polynomials would be an easy next step.

I disagree *somewhat* with Raphael.  Coding some simple functions can give you a better appreciation when you do use something like WolframAlpha.